# How to display multiple custom objects in single VF PDF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf

I'm displaying three design in a Apex using 'renderAs' option. But,i required to display all the designs in single page. By default, it is taking one design per one page. Any ideas?

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="tickets_1_cls" standardStylesheets="false" showChat="false" showHeader="false" renderAs="pdf" >
<apex:outputPanel >
<apex:repeat value="{!Tickets}" var="tic">
<apex:outputText value="{!tic}" escape="false" ></apex:outputText><br/>
</apex:repeat>

</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

My Apex class is:

```
public with sharing class tickets_1_cls {
public contact Content { get; set; }
public Designer_Content_Data__c c{get;set;}

public List<String> getTickets() {
List<String> str1 = new List<string>();
content = new Contact();
c = [SELECT name,designer_data FROM Designer_Content_Data__c limit 1];    
for(integer i=0;i<4;i++)
{
 Content.t_c_textare_rich__c  = c.Designer_data;
str1.add(Content.t_c_textare_rich__c);
}
 return str1;
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused by your question. You show code to output one page, but tell us you want to display 3 pages. Do you want to output 3 PDF pages at the same time, all as part of a single PDF? Do they all use the same controller? Do they all use the same page code? We need more information to answer your question.

Comment: @ crmprogdev , sorry for the confusion. I want to put all the designs in First page of the PDF. If you execute above code, in the single PDF it will show the designs in 3 pages(if you open the downloaded PDF in PDF reader it must show in one page not with 3 pages). Hope it will break your confusion.

Comment: Does it do that because there's too much content? I don't see where you've specified any CSS and have disable standard stylesheets. Is the spacing too large or the font size too large? If the latter, then you need to write some custom CSS to change the font size to use a smaller font and less spacing. Adding a screen shot to your post (click on edit at bottom left) to add an image of one of the pages would be helpful.

Comment: Not sure we have enough information to go off of to help you out. You are declaring {!Tickets} as your repeater item with a value of {!tic} as what you are displaying. But the apex class does not have either of those defined.

Comment: @crmprogdev Ok,i got your point. I want to display the Designs in matrix format. For ex, if an end user gives 2X2(rows X Columns) then the pdf should be generated in that way. Is this requirement is possible by altering CSS? Any better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to vary the number of columns, altering the CSS would be one way of doing it. The issue is, how to balance the two columns so that the content is equally spread between the two columns. I'd expect this to require the page to be pre-composed inside the controller before it's sent to the page.

From what I can see, you have a RTF string that your controller is passing to the VF page. You have a couple of options here. Normally, the easiest way to output a PDF is to put it in a table. If you know you'll always have two columns, that would simplify things for you. You'll want to specify right and left margins or use a 3rd spacer column. If you don't know how many columns you'll always have, your controller and page, will be more complex as you'll also need to pass variables to your CSS or page layout. Regardless of what you do, you'll need to add CSS that changes the font size of your RTF content so it will all fit on a single page if that's the requirement you've been given.

If you plan to do this "on the fly", you may possibly need to do this using in-line formatting or by passing a variable (Note: I have never tried this) based on the total number of characters in your string since you'll know that a single page can only hold a maximum of "x" number of character before it will overflow onto the next page. I'd start by getting the length of the string. You may need to search for line breaks if you need to split this into two columns.

I'm assuming your RTF string already specifies a font. You'll want to reduce the font size and adjust the margins so it will all fit on the page. Your page will need to include the CSS for you to do this rather than having a separate style sheet. In-line formatting, may be easier if you can't access what's in the `<Head>` of the page. Again, that's something I've never attempted to do.

Since I don't know precisely what your requirements are, I'm going to provide you with 3 references that should give you most, if not all of what you need in order to create the code for what you want to do. The first is [Creating Professional PDF Documents with CSS and Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_Professional_PDF_Documents_with_CSS_and_Visualforce) which shows how to compose a PDF with pagination using a controller to calculate the page break points which is the essence of what you want to do; making certain that you don't exceed the break point where a new page will be generated. The next is [Best Practices for Rendering PDFs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_additional_render_pdf.htm). You might also find the following blog post by kenji776 on his [Dynamic PDF Generator](https://iwritecrappycode.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/dynamic-pdf-generator/#comments) helpful to you as well.